# how to reload javascript code block

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I need to reload a block of javascript every amount of time.. say

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var frame = some sort of code;
</script>
```

i need that block of any function to be reloaded every 15 seconds without reloading the page itself .. something like jQuery time out but i don't know how to apply it.. 
any idea?

Comment: setTimeout ( frame , 15000 );

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function foo() {
    // do something here

    if (needRepeat) {
        setTimeout(foo, 15000);
    }
}

setTimeout(foo, 15000);
```

Comment: what if i want to reload script from src like <script type="text/javascript" src="${rootPath}scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script> how can this be reloaded

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1671522/eval-or-load-a-remote-script-several-times

Comment: i did that  <script type="text/javascript">//<!--
            setInterval(function() {
function scriptc(a,b){
  var __d=document;
  var __h = __d.getElementsByTagName("head").item(0);
  var s = __d.createElement("script");
  s.setAttribute("src", a);
  s.id = b;
  __h.appendChild(s);
}

}, 15000);
scriptc("http://pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/show_ads.js");

// --></script>     but it didn't work at all

Comment: move scriptc out from anonymous function to global block

Answer (score 1):

```
var frame;
setInterval(function() {
  frame = someSortOf.Code();
}, 15000);
```

That will execute the provided function every 15 seconds, setting your value.  Note the `var frame` is declared outside the function, which gives it global scope and allows it to persist after your function executes.

You should not really "reload" a script.  What you really want to do is simply run an already loaded script on a set interval.

Comment: what if i want to reload script from src like  <script type="text/javascript"  src="${rootPath}scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script>  how can this be reloaded

Comment: Why would you want to reload jQuery?

Comment: just as example i donot want to :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout('function()', 15000);` - put this line of code at the end of the `function()` so that it calls itself again after 15000ms.

The other way is just to call `setInterval('function()', 15000);` and this will call your `function()` every 15000ms.

The difference between the first and the second one is that the first calls the function after specific milliseconds (only once, so you need to insert it in the function itself) and the second one just calls the function every n milliseconds.

Comment: what if i want to reload script from src like <script type="text/javascript" src="${rootPath}scripts/jQuery/jquery.min.js"></script> how can this be reloaded