# Reload jQuery Function after PrettyPhoto has been triggered

Tags: jquery, function, reload

I hope the title is self-explanatory. Either way, **I am trying to reload (or re-read) a function in jQuery, after another process has been triggered** (in this case, the prettyPhoto plug-in).

This is my current jQuery function:

```
        /** Scrolling Sidebar function **/
            var $sidebar   = $(".sideBar"),
                $window    = $(window),
                $mainImage = $(".mainImage"),
                offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
                threshold  = $mainImage.height() - $sidebar.height(),
                topPadding = 15;

    <?php if ( $options['scroll_sidebar'] == true ) { ?>
        if( $mainImage.height() >= 400 ) {
            $window.scroll(function() {
                if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
                    if( $('.sideBar').has('.zoomImage').length ) {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: threshold + 50
                        });
                    } else {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: threshold + 60
                        });
                    }
                } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: '40px'
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    <?php } ?>
```

And prettyPhoto gets triggered when an anchor tag with the class fullSize is clicked.

I followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3810472/how-to-reload-javascript-code-block) thread to reload a 'code block', using the setTimeout method. This is what I did: *(wrapped the previous code within a function, used setTimeout inside of that function and then called the setTimeout outside of the function)*

```
    /** Scrolling Sidebar function **/
function scrollSidebar() {
            var $sidebar   = $(".sideBar"),
                $window    = $(window),
                $mainImage = $(".mainImage"),
                offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
                threshold  = $mainImage.height() - $sidebar.height(),
                topPadding = 15;

    <?php if ( $options['scroll_sidebar'] == true ) { ?>
        if( $mainImage.height() >= 400 ) {
            $window.scroll(function() {
                if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
                    if( $('.sideBar').has('.zoomImage').length ) {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: threshold + 50
                        });
                    } else {
                        $sidebar.stop().animate({
                            marginTop: threshold + 60
                        });
                    }
                } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                    });
                } else {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: '40px'
                    });
                }
            });
        }

        $('a.fullSize').click(function() {
            setTimeout(scrollSidebar, 1000);
        });
<?php } ?>

    }
setTimeout(scrollSidebar, 1000);
```

Sadly that did not work. So, do you have any ideas as to how I could reload/re-read a function once another action/plug-in has been triggered?

Thanks!
Chris

Answer (score 2, accepted):

" I am trying to reload (or re-read) a function in jQuery, after another process has been triggered"

why are you calling setTimeout?  this will trigger the function call after certain amount of time and then do  loop/repeat every 1000ms. If you just want to reload the function, just call function itself.

```
 $('a.fullSize').click(function() {
            scrollSidebar();
        });
```

EDIT:
Your pretty Image probably does something that affects the  Scrolbar. However, http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyphoto-jquery-lightbox-clone/documentation/  has callback attribute. So do ii like this (callback function will be called whenever a perryimaege has been closed as the problem you were having is when it prettyimage gets open. Soin that respect taht's why click event didn't solve your problem (code probably was working)) You needed something AFTEr the image is closed

```
$("a[rel^='prettyPhoto']").prettyPhoto({
        allow_resize: true,
        theme: 'facebook', /* light_rounded / dark_rounded / light_square / dark_square / facebook */
        callback: sideBar
    });
```

and declare your sidebar on other place

```
function sideBar()
{
    var $sidebar   = $(".sideBar"),
    $window    = $(window),
    $mainImage = $(".mainImage"),
    offset     = $sidebar.offset(),
    threshold  = $mainImage.height() - $sidebar.height(),
    topPadding = 15;

    if( $mainImage.height() >= 400 ) {
        $window.scroll(function() {
            if ($window.scrollTop() > threshold) {
                if( $('.sideBar').has('.zoomImage').length ) {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: threshold + 50
                    });
                } else {
                    $sidebar.stop().animate({
                        marginTop: threshold + 60
                    });
                }
            } else if ($window.scrollTop() > offset.top) {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: $window.scrollTop() - offset.top + topPadding
                });
            } else {
                $sidebar.stop().animate({
                    marginTop: '40px'
                });
            }
        });
    }   
}
```

working code from your webiste  http://jsfiddle.net/qeDwM/

Comment: Nope. setInterval does what you said, not setTimeout. Furthermore, I need my function to work BEFORE and AFTER the prettyPhoto has been triggered. That's why I need to reload after prettyPhoto has been triggered.

Comment: @cr0z3r My bad it looked as if `setTimeout(scrollSidebar, 1000);` is inside `scrollSidebar()` fucntion which in that case it will repeat every  1000ms and hence behaving like setIntevral. As for  your question..where is this `prettyPhoto ` triggered (you say afret 'a.fullSize' is clicked, but that calls ` setTimeout(scrollSidebar, 1000);` and what is `your function` - scrollSidebar()?? (pardon if I am being assretive). Finally,  why do you need timeout event? Just call function itself.

Comment: As I said, I followed that thread about reloading a 'block of code'. I had never needed to reload a jQuery function before, so I did what what answer on that thread said. This is the problem: http://bit.ly/he94BR (refresh the site if the scrolling doesn't work). Now click the image to open it with prettyPhoto; you will notice that the scrolling feature has stopped working. That's my problem. Thanks man.

Comment: @cr0z3r firstly, the question you were follwing was  `I need to reload a block of javascript every amount of time`.so to reload a function every specific time (looping). But regardless. Again what you need is simply to call your function again. Now, when you give example of the code its easier to understand.I've updated my answer woth working code. Apparently PrettyImage had a callbakc function (just something you needed. not click even, but AFTER the image is closed as PrettyyImage was screwing up your fucntion).If its solution working please mark answer as correct and upovte! :). thanks man

Comment: Hey man, thanks so much! So far, this works great. HOWEVER, the scroll function does not work before I trigger prettyPhoto. It works only after pretytPhoto has been triggered. I tried putting the function sideBar inside of (document).ready() as well, but that didn't change anything.

Comment: Never mind, I missed the call function of sideBar at the bottom. Thanks so much, this worked flawlessly :)